# javascript logical operator && not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm calling a function bound to a html element using angularjs. This function contains a simple if statement which evaluates to unexpected result.

```
scope.submit=function(){
  var reqFirstDate = dateFilter(scope.date.first, scope.df);
  var reqSecondDate = dateFilter(scope.date.second, scope.df);
  var reqThirdDate = dateFilter(scope.date.third, scope.df);
  console.log("First :"+ reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)); // prints: true
  console.log("Second: "+ reqSecondDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df));// prints: true
  console.log("Third :" + reqThirdDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df));// prints : true
  console.log("Final condition: "+reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) && reqSecondDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) && reqThirdDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)); // prints: false
  if (reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) && reqSecondDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) && reqThirdDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)) { 
   //doSomething 
  }               
}
```

The Final condition evaluates to false.How is that possible?

Comment: Try bracketing them :) those conditions in if.

Comment: Try adding parentheses - `"Final condition: "+reqFirstDate` is the whole thing being compared to `dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)`.

Comment: it might have read (reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) && reqSecondDate) >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol tried this (reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)) && (reqSecondDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)) && (reqThirdDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)) but prints false.

Comment: try this, to check how this fails: `console.log(
 reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df), 
 reqSecondDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df),
 reqThirdDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df),
 dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df),
 reqFirstDate, 
 reqSecondDate, 
 reqThirdDate
)`

Answer (score 1):

The plus operator `+` has higher prececedence over `>=` so this expression (for example)

```
"First :"+ reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)
```

is evaluated as if it were written

```
( "First :"+ reqFirstDate ) >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df)
```

that is obviously not intended.

Using parentheses properly let you fix this:

```
"First :"+ ( reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) )
```

Your code needs the `console.log` lines to be fixed accordingly:

```
console.log("First :" + ( reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df ) ) );
console.log("Second: "+ ( reqSecondDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) ) );
console.log("Third :" + ( reqThirdDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df ) ) );
console.log("Final condition: " + ( reqFirstDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) && reqSecondDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) && reqThirdDate >= dateFilter(scope.minDat, scope.df) ) );
```

Note that you **don't** need extra parentheses into the `if` expression as there is no abiguity there: `>=` is evaluated before `&&`.

You **can** add them if you think your code becomes more readable or you are unsure about operator precedence. I don't think this is the case here.

See **[Javascript Operators Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)** for a complete list of operators and their precedence.

Higher precedence means the expression part is evaluated first.

---

**Bottom note:**

As others pointed out you may take advantage of using commas `,` in `console.log` to print out values or (as in your case) labels/variable names and corresponding values.

```
console.log( 'label:', true );

console.log( 'a>b', a>b );
```